# Non-inline CSS style in inspector without file attribution

Tags: css, internet-explorer-11, ie11-developer-tools

I have the situation outlined in the screenshot attached where the IE11 inspector is showing me a style being applied that I cannot figure out where its coming from.

In this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWXeF.png) you'll see the inline styles, as expected, and some styles with details on what style sheet and line number they are coming from.

However, the second style - .cke { visibility: hidden } - is not inline nor is it attributed to a style sheet.

Where is this style coming from?  I've used grep to search through the source files for this and can't find anything.  Hoping someone here can point me in the right direction.

[image]

Comment: So you know where all the other `.cke` styles are coming from but not the `.cke` style?

Comment: Is your site using ckeditor? http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: Correct, we are using ckeditor.  Other non-inline styles all identify what file they come from.  This one doesn't.

Comment: Clearly it's coming form the ckeditor code, you just haven't found it yet.